# Insert datetime in procedure SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to add a CreatedDate(DATETIME) column to the User table and in the user registration procedure you need to set the column to DATETIME NOW (UTC 0+).

I added a column. But how to add to the procedure?

```sql
INSERT INTO Users(Email, Username, [Password], [Name], Surname, GETDATE(0+))
```

> --ERROR: Incorrect syntax near '('.

The server is in another country, so the time is written two hours earlier. I need the time that I have in my country, that is, 2 hours later

Comment: What's wrong with [`GETUTCDATE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/getutcdate-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) or [`SYSUTCDATETIME`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/sysutcdatetime-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)? Also, what is the table variable trying to achieve? You just `INSERT` into it and then `SELECT` from it. Why both why it? Just `OUTPUT` the results.

Comment: You've put `GETDATE(0+)` in your column list for the insert statement. that should just be the column name (`CreatedDate`), i.e.  `INSERT INTO Users(Email, Username, [Password], [Name], Surname, CreatedDate) OUTPUT .... ` - everything else seems fine. If you always want the current utc time though, it seems a bit redundant to even have this as a parameter in the prodcedure, just use `GETUTCDATE` as Larnu has suggested

Answer (score 4):

You can just add a default to the column, no setting needed:

```
Alter Table Users Add CreatedDate datetime2 Default SysUtcDateTime()
```

Comment: the server is in another country, so the time is written two hours earlier

Comment: UTC is (by definition) the same everywhere, so the server location won't matter. You'd just need to convert back to your local time when retrieving the date if necessary